# Image not rendering in Visualforce Email Template

Tags: visualforce-component, email-template, images, rendering

I am using a visualforce component in which I have an image tag that is rendering in the org, but when I am sending it via Email the image is getting rendered.

Visualforce Component

```
<apex:component controller="qrcodetestController" access="global">
    <apex:image value="data:image;base64,{!QRCodeBase64}" />
</apex:component>
```

Visualforce Email Template

```
<messaging:emailTemplate subject="Your QR code is as below" recipientType="Contact" relatedToType="Contact">
   <messaging:htmlEmailBody >
   <c:QRCodeTestVFComp />
    </messaging:htmlEmailBody>
</messaging:emailTemplate>
```

EmailTemplate in Org

[image]

Actual Email

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Outlook does not support base64 format that was the conclusion, I answered my self.